# Is this dependency propogation an anti-pattern, and how do I remove it?

Tags: design-patterns, anti-patterns, encapsulation

Module A contains a gap buffer for manipulating text and some associated methods. Relevant to this question is the dependency on a Module B, used for syntax highlighting of text.

Module A also provides a type that wraps its gap buffer with more *stuff*, and brings in some convenience methods for dealing with syntax highlighting, putting Module B in a public API.

This looks like the leaking of an implementation detail: depending modules must know about Module B to use A, even if all they really want is what A provides, and couldn't care less about B.

Is this an (anti-)pattern? If so, does it have a common name, and how can I refactor it out?

Comment: Are you the owner of both modules? Can you clarify why the Module A needs to exist at all instead of being exposed by Module B?

Comment: @VincentSavard both modules are open source, and I can modify them as necessary. Module A provides a context within which constructs from Module B operate, in a fairly awkward way where A *almost* encapsulates B, but 'requires' B to be exposed for coherent APIs, if that makes any sense. Thanks!

Comment: @DocBrown thanks for the feedback; I've added some specifics and rephrased most of it. Tell me if you have any more questions!

Comment: This is still context dependent.    For example, if you're using a UI Framework or library such as Angular/React/Vue, then you may have other libraries which are built specifically for that framework/library, but the developer will need to know about both.  (For example: Ionic builds on top of Angular,  NuxtJS builds on top of Vue, etc.)

Comment: @CtrlAltF2: ok, I think this edit heavily improves your question, retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is neither a pattern or an anti-pattern, it is simply a trade-off between two valid design choices:

1. Designing Module A in a way that the usage of Module B is just an implementation detail, or
2. Designing Module A in a way it exposes parts (for example, types) from Module B in public.

**Each of those two options can be sensible**, and there is no hard-and-fast-rule which one is "better", or which one to prefer over the other. Choice #1 may require a lot of additional encapsulating code. It may require to replicate types in A which are already there in B, maybe more boilerplate code than code which is reused from B. On the other hand, it has the advantage that a user of A does not have to deal with B, and B can be more easily updated or exchanged.

To make a choice, you need to assess if exposing B is really a problem or perfectly acceptable. There are a lot of factors which come into play here, starting from who maintains B, how often B gets changed, how often the public API of B gets changed, how large B is, how much code from B is used inside A, how much code can be saved  by exposing B, up to license considerations.